# A fact regarding the interaction of powers and commutators in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Definition: $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$

Let G be a group and let $x,y \in G$ such that x and y commute with [x,y]. Prove that $(xy)^n = x^ny^n[y,x]^{n(n-1)/2}$

So I've tried to prove it using that xy = yx[x,y] but it seems that the only way it could be true is if x,y also commute with [y,x]

Comment: But since $[x,y] = [y,x]^{-1}$ that is also true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we prove by induction on n that $yx^n[x,y]^n = x^ny$. We know that $yx[x,y] = yxx^{-1}y^{-1}xy = xy$ so it holds for $n=1$. Now suppose $yx^n[x,y]^n = x^ny$ then $yx^{n+1}[x,y]^{n+1} = yx^n[x,y]^{n}x[x,y] = x^nyx[x,y] = x^nyxx^{-1}y^{-1}xy=x^{n+1}y $

Now we prove by induction on that $(xy)^n=x^ny^n[y,x]^{n(n−1)/2}$. We know that $xy= xy[x,y]^{0}$ so it holds for $n=1$. Now, suppose $(xy)^n=x^ny^n[y,x]^{n(n−1)/2}$ then $(xy)^{n+1} = xyx^ny^n[y,x]^{n(n−1)/2} = xyx^ny^n[x,y]^n[y,x]^n[y,x]^{n(n−1)/2} = xyx^n[x,y]^ny^n[y,x]^{n(n+1)/2} = xx^nyy^n[y,x]^{n(n+1)/2}$